# Can't get lmfit parameters stderror

Tags: python, lmfit

I am fitting a curve to some data and I want to get the error on the parameters of the fit. After I define the functions I need (I have 2 peaks in my data) I do this:

```
model =  peak1 + peak2 + background
out = model.fit(rate, pars, x=freq)

for param in out.params.values():
    print (param.name, param.value, param.stderr, param.correl)
```

The fit looks good, but the output of my print function is this:

```
line1_intercept 3053.3123218614182 None None
line1_slope -0.21663082088027244 None None
sv1_center 12842.290728247852 None None
sv1_skew 13.665341159225834 None None
sv1_sigma 0.7078607224978566 None None
sv1_amplitude 39.82090733520796 None None
sv1_gamma 0.7078607224978566 None None
sv1_height 22.442613151830642 None None
sv1_fwhm 2.5492258985387557 None None
```

I didn't paste all the parameters here, but for all of them the error and correlation are None. Why is this and how can I fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities for why errorbars and correlations are not calculated.  Without more details about what you are doing (it is always recommended to include a minimal working example and to show complete output), it is not possible to know for sure, but I would guess that one of the Parameters does not actually alter the fit.

Printing the fit report (`print(out.fit_report())`) may give a clue about which Parameter(s) are not altering the fit -- it's possible that some of them have not moved from their initial values, are stuck at some boundary, or have values that push the model component to zero.

Updating the question to give more details might allow us to give better advice.